# PhpStorm does not reformat the complete code properly

Tags: php, phpstorm

Since I have many (bad coded/indented) files, that look like this:
[image]

After doing a reformat, most code is indented right, but some parts still look like this:
[image]

After having a closer look (with sublime) I noticed that these lines are not indented with tabs, but with spaces:
[image]

So why are those parts not indented right with tabs?

Additional question: How can I remove the empty lines for the hole project?

Comment: Please provide your 1) Code Style (`File | Export Settings...`) and 2) sample file to try it on.

Comment: Sample file: http://pastebin.com/Gs2g1YZ1 | Settings: https://goo.gl/SiO90p

Comment: Cannot download the settings -- please make it public.

Comment: Sorry for that, done :)

Comment: As for the empty lines -- I would suggest using regex and replace `\n\n` (2 line endings in a row) by single `\n`. The formatter may also remove them -- but it's done on pre language basis: uncheck things like "Keep line breaks" and put `0` into "Maximum blank lines" fields

Comment: The issue with `<span>` elemenst (spaces instead of tabs and indents) -- you have to remove `span` from the "Keep white spaces inside" list (that's for HTML, obviously).

Comment: I've got rid from the most empty lines -- only those between php blocks left `?>` and `<?php` are left -- I do not see any settings for them.

Comment: Awesome! Do you want to create a answer, so I can select it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue with spaces instead of tabs and original indentation -- you need to remove `span` from the "Keep white spaces inside" list in Code Style for HTML.

Empty lines -- most of them you can get rid if you disable "Keep line breaks" sort of options and put `0` into "Maximum black lines" kind of fields -- there quite a few of them  in each language (HTML & PHP in your case).

Unfortunately those options do not seem to have any effect on empty lines between PHP code blocks (between `'?>` and `<?php`). For such cases I suggest use regex and replace `\n\n` (2 line endings in a row) by single `\n` (you may need to run such replacement few times if you have lots of consecutive empty lines).